# Function parameters, Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I pass parameters to the function as json (Postgres). the set of parameters may change. is it possible to check for the presence of a parameter in a condition? type like case? Thanks!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tmp.f_search(dateFrom timestamp, dateTo timestamp, data_in json DEFAULT NULL::json)
RETURNS TABLE(id character varying, dateodb timestamp )
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
BEGIN

    RETURN QUERY 
      WITH tr AS (
        select t1.id,t1.dateodb
          from t1
         where 
          (case
         when json_object_keys(data_in->'name') is not null then
         t1.name = (data_in->'name') 
         end)
         limit 201)
        select * from tr;
     END
$function$
;
```

If the user passes the date and `"name"` to JSON, the condition should look like

```
where t1.name = (data_in -> 'name')
```

If the user passes also `"surname"`, the condition should be like

```
where t1.name = (data_in -> 'name') and t1.surname = (data_in -> 'surname')
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the problem? Perhaps a default value different from NULL would do what you want.

Comment: I want to check the input parameter for the presence and substitute it in the condition. The set of transmitted parameters may change.

Comment: Can you be specific about what you mean with "presence"? The value is always there. Do you mean that you want to use a different query if the user used the default value?

Answer (score 0):

You could query:

```
WHERE t1.name = data_in->'name'
AND (NOT (data_in ? 'surname') OR t1.surname = data_in->'surname')
```

Of course such a query cannot use an index on `t1.surname` (because of the `OR`).

So you might be better off writing two functions, one of them with an extra parameter `surname` and a different query, instead of stuffing all arguments into a single JSON.

Alternatively, write a function in PL/pgSQL that runs different queries based on the parameters you pass.